# Mongoose unique auto-incrementing slug

Tags: node.js, mongodb, concurrency, mongoose, slug

I'm implementing a `slug` for certain models in my project, and I want to keep it unique and based on the document's data.

```
var user = new User({ name: { first: 'John', last: 'Doe' });
user.save().then(function(user) {}); // user.slug === 'john-doe'

var user2 = new User({ name: { first: 'John', last: 'Doe' });
user2.save().then(function(user) {}); // user.slug === 'john-doe-2'
```

I can successfully implement it, I can even query the DB on `.pre('save')` hook, like so:

```
UserSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    var user = this;
    return User.distinct('slug')
        .exec()
        .then(function(slugs) {
            // generate a unique slug like "john-doe-2",
            // checking it against slugs that are already
            // in the database, and set it to user
            next();
        });
});
```

The only problem is concurrent requests (unlikely, but still probable):

```
var user = new User({ name: { first: 'John', last: 'Doe' }),
    user2 = new User({ name: { first: 'John', last: 'Doe' });

Promise.all([ user.save(), user2.save() ]);
// throws validation error if slug should be unique
```

For that, I'm looking for a solution that will handle validation errors (unique index duplicate) and try to re-save the document with an updated parameter (like "john-doe-2").

Comment: Handling this error in the save could be problematic. You already moved out of the presave handler. You can create another collection 'users-slug' and try to insert the slug to there (slug field should be unique there too). You can do it in the pre save. if you fail there, you can change the slug and try again.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is a year old now, but I had the same problem and came to a solution that does not require client-side retries until the first free slug is found. If you have a second collection `userslugs`, just do

```
var generatedSlug = 'john.doe';

var count = db.accountslugs.findOneAndUpdate({
    _id: generatedSlug
}, {
    $inc: { count: 1 }
}, {
    upsert: true,
    returnNewDocument: true
}).count;

var fullSlug = generatedSlug + ((count === 1) ? "" : "." + count);
```

You end up with a full slug that would be `john.doe` first, then `john.doe.2` and so on.

This method is much faster, because it finds a slug with one query. I did not use mongoose, because this is the only thing this collection has to do and it seemed overkill.

Edit: Just keep in mind your client should validate that `generatedSlug` does not already end with a dot followed by a number, you are gonna run into issues then.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I ended up having a separate model for slugs, kind of like @AmiramKorach suggested. Then I implement a module for getting a slug, which relies on Mongo's 11000 error (duplicate entries).

```
function getSlug(base, counter) {
    if (typeof counter === 'undefined') counter = 0;
    var url = base;
    if (counter > 0) url += '-' + counter;
    var slug = new Slug({ url: url });
    return slug.save()
        .then(function(slug) {
            return slug.url;
        })
        .catch(function(reason) {
            if (reason.code === 11000) return getSlug(base, counter + 1);
            throw reason;
        });
}

Promise.all([
    getSlug('john-doe'),
    getSlug('john-doe'),
    getSlug('john-doe'),
    getSlug('john-doe'),
    getSlug('john-doe'),
    getSlug('john-doe'),
    getSlug('john-doe')
])
.then(function(slugs) {
    // slugs are [ 'john-doe', 'john-doe-1', 'john-doe-2',
    //'john-doe-4', 'john-doe-5', 'john-doe-6', 'john-doe-3' ]
});
```